# Model weirdly stretches and deforms after rigging

Tags: animation, rigging

I have a rigging problem. Whenever I rotate the bones after finished rigging, the weird model errors start appearing. Please help me out or link me to the tutorial that would teach me how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated[image]

[image]

Comment: this may have to do with the IK Pole Angle value but maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help! Actually the answer is Automatic Weights. I tried doing the Weight painting and Vertex Group myself but the results are still not so good until I tried the Automatic Weights (something I didn't know that it existed until now). So, again, thanks a lot to all of you that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the face orientation is right. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and check *Face Orientation*.

The outer surface should be blue. It could also be a scaling problem. Your model and rig should have the scale value 1.000. To do this press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> when object is selected and click on *Scale*.